# Highchart Column chart with additional legend element

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I've written the folowing chart:

```
monthlyColumnChart = Highcharts.chart('MonthlyColumnChart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                load: function (event) {
                    var theSeries = this.series[1];
                    var theCompSeries = this.series[0];
                    var theData = theSeries.data;
                    var theCompData = theCompSeries.data;

                    for (var i = 0; i < theData.length; i++) {
                        var theDataPoint = theData[i].y
                        var theCompDataPoint = theCompData[i].y;
                        if (theData[i].y < theCompData[i].y) {
                            theSeries.points[i].update({
                                color: '#94d200',
                            });
                        } else {
                            theSeries.points[i].update({
                                color: '#d34810',
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            },

            height: 450,
            marginTop: 60,
            spacingBottom: 30,
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            href: " ",
            text: " "
        },
        title: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            useHTML: true,
            x: -10,
            y: 25,
            style: {
                color: 'white',
                'background-color': '#94d200',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '14px',
            },
            text: '&nbsp &nbsp Consumptionoverview current year &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp '
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Jannuar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'kWh'
            }
        }],
        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 10,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

        },
        series: [{
            name: '\u2205 Consumption (kWh)',
            color: 'rgba(152,152,152,1)',
            data: [10,12,11,10,14,12,11,9,17,12,13,11],
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            },
        }, {
            name: 'Consumption (kWh)',
            color: '#94d200',
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            pointPlacement: 0.1,
            data: [9,8,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,9],
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            },
        }]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6r5pb0e/8/

As you can see, I've two series and one series with two different possible colors depending on the value height (see chart.event). The autogenerated legend has both series but only with the one color (default color of the column). What i need is an additional legend item for the second color including the color and a description. Is there a way to manualy add this legend item?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a separate series for every color.

Comment: Thank's a lot. Sometimes the obvious solution isn't that clear.